# Excel IF function with declared value in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file where I need to decide the outcome through an IF function (I need to put the formula with VBA). My code looks like below however, I am not able to get it done.

```
Dim WB1, ATB, Prod As Workbook
Dim Ws1, Ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Cnt1, Cnt2 As Long
Dim i, j As Long
Dim Hname As String
Dim Bdate As Variant


Set WB1 = ThisWorkbook
Set Ws1 = WB1.Sheets("Home")
Set Ws2 = WB1.Sheets("Control")
Set Ws3 = WB1.Sheets("RAW DATA")

    Bdate = InputBox("Input date in mm/dd/yyyy format")
    Bdate = Format(Bdate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
Ws3.Range("AF2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-22]<DATEVALUE(""07/01/2019""),""<07/01/2019"","">=07/01/2019"")"
```

I need to replace the ***07/01/2019*** value with ***Bdate***.

thanks for your help!

Comment: Join using & sign, i.e. something like this....     Ws3.Range("AF2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-22]<DATEVALUE(""" & Bdate & """),""<" & Bdate & ""","">=" & Bdate & """)"

Comment: It worked perfectly!!Thanks Bilal. I